# How to replace a string containing [] in python

Tags: python, string, list

Please excuse me if my question is too basic since I am new to python.

I have a string as follows.

```
Data=['A', 'B', 'C', 'X [7:0] Y', '[3:0] K' ]
```

I want to change it to the following format.

```
Data=['A', 'B', 'C', 'Y X [7:0]', 'K [3:0]']
```

Is there any way in python to do it.

Comment: yes there is, please make an attempt before asking

Comment: Its kind of unclear what you're asking. If a string contains brackets you want the brackets to be moved to the end of the string? Why does Y get moved before X? how are you wanting to modify these strings?

Comment: The string is not always the same. So there is no way to find out in advance how it will look like. Hence I am thinking to automate the process using python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l=[]
for string in Data:
    if '[' in string:
        l.append(string[string.index(']')+1:].strip()+" "+string[:string.index('[')]+string[string.index('['):string.index(']')+1].strip())
    else:
        l.append(string)
print(l)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'Y X [7:0]', 'K [3:0]']
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a helper function and utilising `str.split`. This may not be the most efficient answer, but it should give an idea of how you can structure your logic.

```
def mover(x):
    if '[' in x:
        lst = x.split()  # split by whitespace
        idx = next(i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if '[' in j)  # find index
        lst.append(lst.pop(idx))  # move item to end
        return ' '.join(lst)
    else:
        return x

Data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'X [7:0] Y', '[3:0] K' ]

res = [mover(x) for x in Data]

print(res)

['A', 'B', 'C', 'X Y [7:0]', 'K [3:0]']
```